# How to set intercept of linear regression line in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams, graphs

In excel, one can set the intercept of the trendline that goes through a scatterplot. Is it possible to do the same thing in pgfplots, for example making the linear regression line go through the origin or some other y intercept? I apologize for not providing an example of a graph, as this feature will influence my decision to use excel or pgfplots.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TexSE.  Linear regression in pgfplots is dealt with in some detail in section 4.24 of the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots), on p.401ff in my local copy.   Of course, the fact that there *is* a manual, and that everyone should probably read at least some of it, might also influence your decision to stick with Excel or not.